# How to add marker on Google map from Rdlc report

Tags: google-maps, rdlc

Hi Currently I am working on an Rdlc report in which I am going to a google map on click of a textbox . I am also passing lattitude and longitude to the url so it goes to that particular location only.So now I want to add a marker in that specific location.So my question is

Is it possible to add marker on google map from an rdlc report
If yes please help me 
The URL which I have given in the go to URL expression is
`https://www.google.com.my/maps/@Fields!TRIPENDLATITUDE.Value,!Fields!TRIPENDLONGITUDE.Value,?hl=en`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the solution it works great the whole URL is given below

`="https://www.google.com.my/maps/place/" & Fields!TRIPSTARTLATITUDE.Value & "," & Fields!TRIPSTARTLONGITUDE.Value & ",15z?hl=en"`